# How do i drop a table if exists jpa h2 spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to add a users entity as manytoone to reviewers entity, however i am getting the following error

```
SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000478: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists user cascade
```

Here is my entity

```
   @Entity
    public class Review extends BaseEntity {


    public Review(int rating, String description) {
        this.setRating(rating);
        this.setDescription(description);
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    private Course course;

    public User getReviewer() {
        return reviewer;
    }

    public void setReviewer(User reviewer) {
        this.reviewer = reviewer;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User reviewer;


    public Review() {
        super();
    }

    }
```

I have tried added cascade = CascadeType.ALL to the property but it is not working

Comment: Can you give us some more details about what code is executing when the error occurs?

Comment: public void setReviewer(User reviewer) {
        this.reviewer = reviewer;
    }

Comment: I mean, please include a large chunk of the code surrounding the point of failure. Just the setter is not enough context.  Especially since that would not normally trigger a table deletion.

Comment: thats the code, the rest is right their in the post. thats it

Comment: it fails when trying to save the user actually   users.saveAll(students);

Comment: fixed it, had to rename the entity user to user_entity

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below property in the application.properties.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

This property will create a new table if the table does not exist.